# python dict: nested dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to update keys from a JSON file (which is then converted to python dictionary). I would like to have a nested dictionary within my updated files but I don't know how to do this.

```
f = dict(
    source=result['sourcefile'], 
    destination=result['destinationfile']
)
```

In this code, I have `result` which is my JSON output. I have the keys `sourcefile` and `destinationfile` are the keys I get from the API. I would like to change them to `source` and `destination`. This code does the job until here; however, I would like my dictionary to be nested (whether with a `list` or another `dict`).
Something like below:

```
{"F":{"source":"samplevalue","destination":"samplevalue"}}
```

Comment: Your first code snippet is syntactically incorrect in Python. Please fix it.

Comment: @DYZ code is fine.

Comment: @DYZ sorry, edited

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych there was a comma left at the end of the final key

Comment: @adelrahimi that is not a problem in python.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Sorry, I mean the second snippet.

Comment: @DYZ its not a snippet of code, i just wanted to show what i wanted

Comment: @adelrahimi It is not clear what you want. `["source":"samplevalue", "destination":"samplevalue"]` is neither a list nor a dictionary.

Comment: Your second snippet isn't valid JSON either. I find your goal and your problem very unclear. You can have a dict in a dict; it is not a problem and works just like having a string or int in a dict.  They're all objects in python.

Comment: I added a valid json

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code that incorporates the code you showed and produces the JSON you show.  It simply makes the object as described and encodes it as JSON.

```
import json

result = {'sourcefile': "samplevalue", 'destinationfile':"samplevalue"}

f = dict(
                 source=result['sourcefile'],
                         destination=result['destinationfile']
                                         )
g = {"F": f}

print( json.dumps(g) )
```

Comment: this is not efficient, what if the output was more complex?

Comment: What efficiency are you concerned about?  Your question says that the output is like this, not more complex.  If it addresses your undisclosed concern, the json module has a function [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) that writes to a stream.  If that isn't what you seek, then I recommend asking a new question.